# Multiple select tags in a form. How to query all of them?

Tags: php, sql

When clicking the submit button I want to query all selected options from the form, but this does not happen. It takes into consideration only the last option (EU). If anyone can help. Thanks!

```
<form name="filter_form" method="POST" action="display_data.php">
    Select a country:
    <select name="country">
        <option name="country" value="AL">All</option>
        <option name="country" value="AU">Austria</option>
        <option name="country" value="BE">Belgium</option>
    </select>
    Select Type:
    <select name="ASS">
        <option name="ASS" value="all">All</option>
        <option name="ASS" value="think">Think Tanks</option>
        <option name="ASS" value="network">Networks</option>
        <option name="ASS" value="NGO">NGOs</option>
    </select>
    Select EU Attitude:
    <select name="EU">
        <option name="EU" value="all">All</option>
        <option name="EU" value="PRO">PRO EU</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit Filter" />
</form>
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
    switch($_POST['country'])
    {
    case 'BE' : $countryName = 'Belgium';
                break;
    case 'AU' : $countryName = 'Austria';
                break;
    case 'BU' : $countryName = 'Bulgaria';
                break;

    default : $countryName = '';
              break;
    }
    $where = '';
    if($countryName != '')
    {
        $where = "WHERE Country='".$countryName."'";
    }   
}

if(isset($_POST['ASS']))
{
    switch($_POST['ASS'])
    {
    case 'think' : $type = 'Think Tank';
                break;
    case 'network' : $type = 'Network';
                break;
    case 'NGO' : $type = 'NGO';
                break;
    default : $type = '';
              break;
    }
    $where = '';
    if($type != '')
    {
         if(!empty($type)){
        $where .= " AND Type='".$type."'";
    } else {
        $where = "WHERE Type='".$type."'";
    }   
    }   

}


if(isset($_POST['EU']))
{
    switch($_POST['EU'])
    {
    case 'PRO' : $eus = 'PRO EU';
                break;
    case 'REFORM' : $eus = 'Reform EU';
                break;
    case 'ANTI' : $eus = 'Eurosceptic';
                break;
    default : $eus = '';
              break;

    }
    $where = '';
    if($eus != '')
    {
        if((!empty($countryName)) || (!empty($type))){
        $where .= " AND Attitude='".$eus."'";
    } else {
        $where = "WHERE Attitude='".$eus."'";
        }
        }
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM think ".$where.""); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep resetting your $where:

```
 $where = '';
```

Set it once at the top, then let it run.

Answer (score 1):

In each block you reset the where clause `$where =''`.

Remove this from the `ASS` and `EU` blocks and put it at the start of the script only to initialise the variable as an empty string.